# Automatically download files in specified folder regardless of type

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-headers

How can I make it so that when a user visits a file in a specified folder, I can force the file to be downloaded?

I know it's possible to do this type by type using .htaccess and you can force a file to download using a php script, but how can I force download the file they visited within the specified folder without a php script?

Currently, when you view a file that the browser knows how to read, it reads the file instead of downloading it. I want it to automatically download all files in the folder instead of reading ones that the browser supports.

Comment: ...as opposed to what? What's happening now when the user visits the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "mod_headers" module should be available.. then you can add this to your .htaccess file.

By type:

```
<FilesMatch "\.jpg$">
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
</FilesMatch>
```

A specific file by name:

```
<Files test.jpg>
    Header set Content-Disposition attachment
    Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
</Files>
```

Put it to the .htaccess file in the specific folder with your file to download.

For the whole folder leave out Files/FilesMatch directive.

Comment: As I said in my question, I was wondering how to do this without writing this for each filetype the browser can read, and instead do it by applying this to the whole folder not just each type.

Comment: Use phpinfo() to check if it is installed, but I guess without you would get a 500. Maybe you can't override headers or add own in your hosting environment??!